# D3.js: Pie graph, different color of chart separators?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, pie-chart

Is it possible to have different colors for chart segments separators?

[image]

On the image above, I want to add different colors (only) for separators like for example green, orange and red zone. It should looks something like this

[image]

Comment: Tnx for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be easiest to draw lines on top of the wedge boundaries.

Calculate
1. the location of the center of the pie,
2. the point on the circumference where the two `arc`'s of interest meet

and draw the [line](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#lines) between these two points.  Change the `stroke` color as needed.

For context, and a possible alternative, the shape of a pie wedge is a d3 `arc` which is actually a `path`.  Therefore it also has a `stroke`, which presumably could be controlled programmatically.  But the `arc`'s `path` is the whole perimeter of the wedge, and thus it might be difficult to color only one "spoke" segment.